# Not Enough Inputs in Matlab Function Handle

Tags: matlab, function, handle

I have a script file that loads data from an Excel spreadsheet and calls a function:

```
clear;clc

offsets = [0 0];
crossed = 0; % fourbar is open, not crossed
L = xlsread('lab5data.xlsx','A:A')/100;
theta_s = xlsread('lab5data','B:B'); % Servo angles [deg]
theta_l_exp = xlsread('lab5data.xlsx','C:C');

sum_sq_error  = fourbar_calibration( offsets,L,crossed,theta_s,theta_l_exp)

fc_handle = @(offsets,L,crossed,theta_s,theta_l_exp)               
fourbar_calibration(offsets,L,crossed,theta_s,theta_l_exp);

optimal_offsets = fminsearch(fc_handle,[15 15],[],sum_sq_error);
```

The script calls this function:

```
function [ sum_sq_error ] = fourbar_calibration(     

offsets,L,crossed,theta_s,theta_l_exp)

[theta_l] = fourbar( L, crossed, theta_s, offsets );

sum_sq_error = sum((theta_l_exp-theta_l).^2)

end
```

That function calls this second function while running to calculate theta_l:

```
function [ theta_l ] = fourbar( L, crossed, theta_s, offsets )

[theta_2] = 180 - theta_s + offsets(1);

K1 = L(1)/L(2); % fourbar K values
K2 = L(1)/L(4);
K3 = ( L(1)^2 + L(2)^2 - L(3)^2 + L(4)^2 ) / ( 2 * L(2) * L(4) );

A = cosd(theta_2) - K1 - K2.*cosd(theta_2) + K3; % Quadratic input A
B = -2.*sind(theta_2);                           % Quadratic input B
C = K1 - (K2 + 1).*cosd(theta_2) + K3;           % Quadratic input C

if crossed == 1 % Angle of rocker w.r.t. ground link if fourbar is crossed
   theta_4 = 2.*atand( (-B + sqrt(B.^2 - 4.*A.*C)) ./ (2.*A));

real_num_check = B.^2 - 4.*A.*C; % Creates array of values to check for     invalud servo values
check_index = find(real_num_check<1);
theta_4(check_index) = NaN;

    if length(check_index) == length(theta_4)
    error('No valid servo angles - there is a mistake somewhere!!!')
    end

    if nargout == 0
    theta_l = 180 - theta_4 + offsets(2); % Launch angle w.r.t. horizontal
    plot(theta_s,theta_l)
    title('Launch Angles vs Servo Angles')
    xlabel('Servo Angles [deg]')
    ylabel('Launch Angles [deg]')
    grid on
    end

[theta_l] = 180 - theta_4 + offsets(2); % Launch angle w.r.t. horizontal

end

if crossed == 0 % Angle of rocker w.r.t. ground link if fourbar is open
    [theta_4] = 2.*atand( (-B - sqrt(B.^2 - 4.*A.*C)) ./ (2.*A));

    real_num_check = B.^2 - 4.*A.*C; % Creates array of values to check for     invalud servo values
    check_index = find(real_num_check<1);
    theta_4(check_index) = NaN;

    if length(check_index) == length(theta_4)
        error('No valid servo angles - there is a mistake somewhere!!!')
    end

    if nargout == 0
    [theta_l] = 180 - theta_4 + offsets(2); % Launch angle w.r.t. horizontal
    plot(theta_s,theta_l)
    title('Launch Angles vs Servo Angles')
    xlabel('Servo Angles [deg]')
    ylabel('Launch Angles [deg]')
    grid on
    end

[theta_l] = 180 - theta_4 + offsets(2); % Launch angle w.r.t. horizontal

end
```

When I run the script file I receive the following error:

```
**Error using @(offsets,L,crossed,theta_s,theta_l_exp)fourbar_calibration(offsets,L,crossed,theta_s,theta_l_exp)
Not enough input arguments.
Error in fminsearch (line 190)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
Error in HW5PPP2 (line 28)
optimal_offsets = fminsearch(fc_handle,[15 15],[],sum_sq_error);**
```

I have tried changing the inputs at the end of the fminsearch argument by adding theta_l and taking away all extra inputs, as well as changing the inputs of the function, but I either get errors telling me I have too many inputs or not enough. I have checked other forum posts and still do not understand why I am getting the error in this particular case.

I would also like to save the value **theta_l** calculated in the middle of the second function, but I don't know how to get it to save to my workspace after it is done running.

Comment: The start point `x0 = [15 15]` must have the same number of coordinates as your function `fc_handle` has parameters. As you are computing `optimal_offsets` it seems to me, that you should define `fc_handle = @(offsets) ....` and change `[15 15]` to `[15]`.

Comment: That did it, and I only had to change the last part of the function: